# Delete all characters after "." in each line

Tags: vim

I have a text file with about 2,000 lines of text and I want to remove a large portion of each line of text.

The text is in this format:

```
Important Text that I care about. Stuff I want to delete
```

I am unsure as to how to delete all of the text after the `.` in each line.

Can someone give me a quick command that would do this?

Comment: @Lucas Can there be multiple periods in each line?  If there are multiple periods, which one are you looking for? Are there lines without periods?

Comment: @Patrick There are not lines without periods, but there are a few lines without periods... does that change anything?

Comment: @Lucas If you have some lines not having a period, then my solution will not work for the lines not having a period. It sounds like you meant to say, "there are not lines with multiple periods".  If there were, an approach would need to address the multiple periods.

Comment: @Patrick You're right, I didn't notice that. I meant, there are not lines with multiple periods, but there are a few lines without periods.. Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Various additional `:normal` solutions:

```
:%norm )Dx
:%norm $T.D
:%norm f.C.
:%norm 0/\. /e<C-v><CR>D
```

[image: :normal]

Comment: Command #1 seems to delete all lines containing no `.`.  
 Command #2 removes final `.`.  
 #3 and #4 seem to work very well. I suppose that `<C-v>` means here “typing `Ctrl + v`, not writing it as is?

Comment: @Qeole, all commands assume the buffer only consists of lines similar to the one in the question. #1 moves to next sentence (`)`), deletes the rest of the line (`D`) and the remaining space (`x`). #2 moves to the end of the line (`$`), moves to the character just after the dot (`T.`) and deletes the rest of the line (`D`). #3 moves to the first dot (`f.`) and change the rest of the line with a dot (`C.`). Yes, `<C-v><CR>` means `Ctrl+v` then `Enter` and should print something that looks like `^M`.

Comment: I just thought it was worth mentioning this assumption (as well as detailing `<C-v>` as you did) :) I'm upvoting.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the third command and it worked out great.

Comment: @tarsis `)` jumps to end of sentence, then `D` cuts text from cursor to EOL, then `x` cuts the trailing space.

Comment: @KolobCanyon did you forget the colon before `%`?

Answer (score 40):

With substitutions:

```
:%s/\..*/./
```

With `:normal` command:

```
:%norm f.lD
```

Comment: Guess the "1" is redundant. %norm f.D would work just as well.

Comment: @sankoz Actually it's not a 1 but a l (L). And I put it there to keep the dot at the end of the line.

Comment: Substitution helped me a lot, I need to delete everything after "/" character so I did `:%s/\/.*//g` where I substitute everything after "/" character with "" empty string and I do it `g` - globally

Answer (score 11):

**Use the Substitution Ex Command to Trim All Lines**

This is very similar to both answers, yet I think there is value in presenting it.

Like the other answers, I just used the ex substitution command:

```
 :%s/[^.]*$//
```

**Explanation of substitution:**

`%` indicates a range for all lines.

`[^.]` is a character class of all non-period characters

`*` is a quantifier indicating 0 or more matches.

`$` is an anchor which communicates to VIM that we want this pattern to match at the end of the line.

---

**Addendum**

The solution assumes each line will have a period, otherwise the command will not work as expected as @Qeole has indicated. Qeole's solution addresses non-periods lines appropriately.

Comment: Note that this command will also delete all lines containing no `.` at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. If "a large portion of each line of text" has a period, this will work as specified; otherwise not.

Comment: @Qeole Waited 4 years to modify my answer to take into consideration your feedback.

Comment: Wow :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `search and replace` "[vim feature](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)" combined with regex: 
`:%s/\..*$//g`

Comment: The final `g` does not look mandatory here. Also, I believe we want to keep the `.` in the end of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

with the cursor at the first character  of first line.

```
fS<Ctrl-V>G$d
```